# Sql progress logging in transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am would like to display progress feedback for user while stored procedure is running (multiple setps). All sql code is in transaction so I am using a service broker to get a real time updates. Could you suggest what is wrong with code below as I am not getting any messages in my queue?
Is there a better way of doing it?

```
--queue
create queue myQueue

--service
create service myLogs
on queue myQueue ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]);

--log handler
create event notification myLogHandler
on  server
for userconfigurable_0
to service 'myLogs', 'current database' ;

--message
EXEC master..sp_trace_generateevent @event_class = 82, @userinfo = N'test msg'

---transaction test
begin transaction
EXEC master..sp_trace_generateevent @event_class = 82, @userinfo = N'tran test msg'
rollback transaction


--receive message
declare @message_body  xml;  
receive  top (1) @message_body = message_body
from myQueue
select @message_body

--display queue  
select * from myQueue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works fine for me though I needed to wait a few moments and run the receive from queue bit again before I saw anything.

Perhaps you need to `ENABLE_BROKER` on the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET  ENABLE_BROKER WITH  ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

(**Warning**: Will kill existing connections to the DB)

Comment: Thank you, I was moving from one db to another and I missed that :)

Comment: I am trying to move above code (with enable_broker) to my test server (SQL2008R2 Standard). If I create a new database everything is ok. But I can’t get it to work on already existing db. I am using sa account so privileges shouldn’t be a problem. The main differences are collation and compatibility level(2005 vs 2008). I have changed compatibility level – no difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't think of anything. Presumably `ENABLE_BROKER` is definitely set? Can you see the user configurable event being fired when using Profiler? If yes to both of those maybe try dropping all objects and creating again.

Comment: Looking at sys.databases is_broker_enabled is 1. I can see it in profiler. I have tried to drop and recreate all objects few times. Database was transferred form SQL 2005 could that affect it? From what I have read so far service broker should work fine between 2005 and 2008.

Comment: Maybe use profiler to trace the various `Broker:` events. See if that sheds any light.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was a strange situation – first sending message was failing because of Error: 15404 State: 11 in relation to deleted AD account. After removing it from SQL logins I started getting Error: 15517 State: 1 which was resolved by: 
`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[testdb] TO [SA] `

Answer (score 3):

An arguably simpler way would be to:

```
--------------------------------
--Worker process 
--------------------------------

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--While in your loop or at each stage of the proc you can do this
INSERT INTO MyLoggingTable VALUES('My Message')

COMMIT

--------------------------------
--Reporting process
--------------------------------

SELECT * FROM MyLoggingTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

The NOLOCK lets you read the progress of the proc even though its logging to it inside the transaction.

NOTE that this allows you to read the data "LIVE" but if the worker process dose a rollback then the data will be removed.

You can get around that by **also** logging to a @MyTable, this will survive the rollback and so you can rollback and then copy the content of @MyTable into MyLoggingTable.