# save point within a transaction and store error message in sql server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which is for inserting data into a table. This procedure is called from asp.net application which handles the transaction start, commit and rollback functionality. Inside the stored procedure there is no transaction.

In  this scenario my application is working fine and it is hosted in the live. Now, inside the store procedure, I have to add a new functionality to insert another table by linked server to another database and if error appears then I have to store it in the database.

We want to implement this insertion in such a way so that the previous sp will be working fine.

Noted that if error from the insertion of linked server comes then entire  process is rolled back and also save point is not working. We can do this by dot net code but this is for more 40 modules, so I have to do this by sp . So, how can we implement this.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the linked server portion in `BEGIN TRY`, `END TRY` and `BEGIN CATCH` `END CATCH`? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN SAVE TRANSACTION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveCustomer]
@Firstname nvarchar(50),
@Lastname nvarchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @ReturnCode int = 1     -- 1 - success
    ,@NewID int
---------------------------------------------- These variables are for TRY/CATCH RAISEERROR and BEGIN TRAN/SAVE POINT use           
    ,@tranCounter int               -- @TranCounter > 0 means an active transaction was started before the procedure was called.
    ,@errorMessage nvarchar(4000)   -- echo error information to the caller.  Message text.
    ,@errorSeverity int             -- Severity.
    ,@errorState int;               -- State

SET @tranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;
IF @tranCounter > 0
    SAVE TRANSACTION SaveCustomer_Tran;
ELSE
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

    INSERT dbo.Customer (
        Firstname
        ,Lastname)
    VALUES (
        @Firstname
        ,@Lastname)

    SET @NewID = scope_identity()

    IF @tranCounter = 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @tranCounter = 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    ELSE
        IF XACT_STATE() <> -1
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SaveCustomer_Tran;

    SELECT @errorMessage = 'Error in [SaveCustomer]: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(), @errorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @errorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@errorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState);
    SET @ReturnCode = -1
END CATCH

SELECT @ReturnCode as [ReturnCode], @NewID as  [NewID]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two accepted ways to escape the current transaction rollback tarpit.

One way is to use a looopback connection. Either via linked server, or from SQLCLR, connect back to the current server and write the `INSERT`, making sure DTC enrollment is not allowed. As the loopback connection is a different transaction, you can safely rollback in the original transaction and preserve the INSERT. This approach has the drawback that is very easy to deadlock yourself.

The other, less known, way is to use [`sp_trace_generateevent`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx) to fire off a [user-configurable event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175164.aspx). This may not seem much, but you can [create event notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx) for these events and then impelemnt handling that does the INSERT in processing the event. Eg. see [Sql progress logging in transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629383/sql-progress-logging-in-transaction). This approach has the drawback of being difficult.